Use quiver representation to study integral extension of Artinian rings
I have some ideas about the integral extension of Artinian rings denoted by $R \subset S$. Since $\mathrm{Spec}(R)$ is finite and discrete, I construct a category $\mathscr{R}$ whose objects are elements in $\mathrm{Spec}(R)$ and morphisms are of the form $\mathrm{Hom}(p,q)=\{f \in \mathrm{Aut}(R):\ f^{\ast}(p)=q\}, f^*: \mathrm{Spec}(R) \to \mathrm{Spec}(R)$.
Clearly it is a quiver, so we can consider the representation $\mathscr{R} \to \mathrm{fin}\mathbf{R}\mbox{-}\mathrm{alg}$ (category of finitely generated $R$-algebra). Denote the category of this kind of quiver representations by $\mathrm{rep}\mathscr{R}$. Since integral extension $R \subset S$ induces essentially surjective functor $\mathscr{S} \to \mathscr{R}$, where $\mathscr{S}$ is the quiver of $\mathrm{Spec}(S)$, thus induces functor $\mathrm{rep}\mathscr{R}\to \mathrm{rep}\mathscr{S}$.
On the other hand, put $Q$ be a quiver, the category of $R$-representations of $Q$ is equivalent to the category of left $kQ$-module, where $kQ$ is path algebra. Suppose $M$ is the left $kQ$-module corresponding to a representation of $\mathscr{R}$, consider the induced representation:  $SQ\otimes_{RQ} M$. Maybe there are some adjoint functor pair containing induced representations？
My question is, is there any theory similar to it already? Or it is just a useless idea? I can not go on. Is it possible to define something like 'character' of this representation or Grothendieck group of the category of quiver representations?
P.S. In order to make the quiver have good property, the definition of $\mathrm{Hom}(p,q)$ can be modified.
